# MongoDB query to find a value from multiple nested json files

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query

I have 500 json files of the following format (Same format. Just different data). I just need the city names from all these files. Can anyone help me with the query.

Example: From the following file, I need the output as San Diego, Newnan, Louisville.

```
{
"clinical_study":{
 "location": [
  {
    "facility": {
      "address": {
        "city": "San Diego",
        "country": "United States"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "facility": {
      "address": {
        "city": "Newnan",
        "country": "United States"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "facility": {
      "address": {
        "city": "Louisville",
        "country": "United States"
      }
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to MongoDB, but it sounds like you don't need a query for the city names. It sounds like you already query for the list of locations, so all you need to do is right a loop to obtain the city from each returned location.

Something like this:

```
// Assume here that clinical is the object in your question
var locations = clinical.clinical_study.locations;
var cityList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length ; i++ ) {
    cityList[i] = locations.facility.address.city;
}
```

This is a naive approach at the very least. I'm not sure how you can do it in a db query itself (I'm familiar with the express module Mongoose, which I don't think allows this. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Can you provide the query for that please

Comment: @Vamshi You haven't explained what it is you want to query. You simply stated that given the object in question, how can you get the cities. If you already have the object in question, you've already performed the query. You have not specified the criteria for querying the given object.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty unclear what you want. But Whatever I understand you wants only city names from given sample collection structure. You can simply use [Mongo Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Here is a query for getting cities:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
      $unwind: "$clinical_study.location"
    }, {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      city: '$clinical_study.location.facility.address.city'
    }
})
```

Comment: I get an error saying,    value at the end of $unwind field path '$clinical_study.location' must be an Array, but is an object.

Comment: Here array `Location` is unwinded not `clinical_study`. Do you provided correct structure in sample data? I am using mongo 3.0 and is working for me.